# 400 Bad Request Postman React Native

Tags: react-native

ARGG! HELP! I'm trying to send a POST request to an authentication API but I keep getting the 400 bad request error message. I use JSON raw. Not sure what I need to do!

[image: Error returned]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is nothing to do with React Native but the authentication API.

I suggest you to check the link if its true and also double check the credentials you enter

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the post body - the format i.e Email address mismatch (case sensitive)
or the password passed if its to be encrypted and passed in body and then
Verify the url and headers